# Legality of empty, unnamed enumeration specifier

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, c++14

In the example in §7.5 (C++14) one finds:

`enum {};   // ill-formed`

But, technically speaking, I think the code is valid.`enum {}` is an *enum-specifier*, and so, it's a *type-specifier*, which is a *decl-specifier*, and thus, it is a *simple-declaration* with an omitted *init-declarator-list*. And this is accepted by §7.5. Note that the *identifier* is optional for an unscoped enumeration. Also, clang compiles this with a warning.

**Edit**

In relation to the answers mentioning that `the *decl-specifier-seq* shall introduce one or more names into the program, or shall redeclare a name introduced by a previous declaration`, I show below a **typedef** declaration that compiles, but whose *decl-specifier-seq* doesn't introduce any name in the declaration:

```
typedef class {} A;
```

Comment: If the specification says something is ill-formed. then is most certainly is ill-formed.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. That section specifically says that unnamed enums with omitted declarator lists need to introduce symbols. It may have been legal if not for that section.... but that section is part of the standard.

Comment: @Sneftel In the grammar, the *enumeration-list* for a *enum-specifier* is optional and in §7.2/7 you'll find this: `If the enumerator-list is empty, the underlying type is as if the enumeration had a single enumerator with value 0.`

Comment: @OllieFord If you're referring to the example: Those aren't normative.

Comment: @OllieFord A comment in an Example is not normative

Comment: @Belloc There are plenty of things that are legal in the grammar but are not legal in C++ because of further restrictions on well-formed programs. `int i = "fish"`, for example.

Comment: The grammar does not specify what programs are valid C++ programs.  It restricts what programs are valid C++ programs (at best; the standard might even have exceptions to that), but it is not the final say.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the C++14 FD, *right above* your example, it is explained why the declaration is ill-formed:

> In a *simple-declaration*, the optional *init-declarator-list* can be
>   omitted only when declaring a class (Clause 9) or enumeration (7.2)
>   […]
>
> In such cases, **the *decl-specifier-seq* shall introduce one or more
>   names into the program, or shall redeclare a name introduced by a
>   previous declaration.**

Hence

```
enum {} e;
enum {a};
```

[Are valid](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4971b123b8488706) - our quote does not apply to the first declaration as it includes an *init-declarator*, and the second one introduces the name `a` as an enumerator. Note that GCC won't compile the first declaration, which is presumably a bug.

You also mentioned the quote

> If the *enumerator-list* is empty, the underlying type is as if the
>   enumeration had a single enumerator with value `0`.

This makes a statement about the underlying type, not the enumeration itself, and is thus irrelevant for this matter.

---

#### Why does `typedef class {} A;` compile?

`A` is an *init-declarator*. Yes, it is - [dcl.dcl]/9:

> If the *decl-specifier-seq* contains the *typedef specifier*, the
>   declaration is called a typedef declaration **and the name of each
>   *init-declarator* is declared to be a *typedef-name***

I.e. the names declared as *typedef-names* are the *init-declarators*, by this definition. Hence there is an *init-declarator-list*, and our above quote isn't applicable.

Comment: But this code compiles `typedef class{} A;`. How do you explain this?

Comment: @Belloc .. that's not omitting the *init-declarator-list*, is it? The *init-declarator* is `A`.

Comment: No, but you have a *decl-specifier* without a name and with an empty *init-delcarator-list*. That is, the *decl-specifier-seq*  is **not** introducing any name in the declaration. And that's what you complained in your answer.

Comment: @Belloc The *init-declarator-list* is **not** empty. Furthermore, `A` is introduced, which is a name, but more importantly, `A` is an *init-declarator* in the declaration `typedef class{} A;`

Comment: What I'm saying in relation to the typedef declaration is that the *decl-specifier*, `class {}` **doesn't** introduce a name into the declaration. The `A` in the declaration is not an `init-declarator-list`, it's a `typedef-name`.

Comment: @Belloc Nope. Sorry, you're simply wrong. `A` is an *init-declarator*. It is also declared as a *typedef-name*, because the specifier `typedef` is present, but that does not change the fact that in this declaration it constitutes an *init-declarator*. If you're categorically denying that, I'm not gonna try to convince you any further.

Comment: A typedef declaration is not a *simple-declaration*. I'm not categorically saying anything. I'm just trying to bring arguments to the discussion.

Comment: See my **Edit** above

Comment: Ok you're right. A *typedef-name* constitutes an *init-declarator-list*. But you still have in this declaration, a *decl-specifier* which **doesn't** introduce any name in the declaration, which goes against your argument: `the decl-specifier-seq shall introduce one or more names into the program, or shall redeclare a name introduced by a previous declaration`.

Comment: I'm finally convinced. Thanks (+1)

Answer (score 2):

There is clear written in the Standard that (7 Declarations)

> 3. ...In such cases, and except for the declaration of an unnamed bit-field (9.6), the decl-specifier-seq **shall introduce one or more
>      names** into the program, or shall redeclare a name introduced by a
>      previous declaration.

This declaration

```
enum {};   // ill-formed
```

does not satisfy the requirement. It introduces neither name into the program.

As for typedef(s) then

> 7.1.3 The typedef specifier 1 Declarations containing the decl-specifier **typedef declare identifiers** that can be used later
>   for naming 94)

Comment: But this code compiles `typedef class{} A;`. How do you explain this?

Comment: @Belloc This declaration introduces name A.

Comment: But the `A` here is not in the *decl-specifier*. It is a *typedef-name*.

Comment: @Belloc decl-specifier-seq is defined like decl-specifier-seq:
decl-specifier attribute-specifier-seqopt

Comment: See my **Edit** above

Answer (score 2):

If you look through the standard, you'll find quite a few things that would be accepted at a purely syntactical level, but are prohibited by the text. This is just one of many instances of that basic idea.

Many of these situations are pretty obvious. Let's consider a really trivial one: a floating point number. Using a syntactical notation similar to that of the standard we could get something like:

"-"*<sub>opt</sub>* digits *<sub>opt</sub>* "."*<sub>opt</sub>* digits *<sub>opt</sub>* ("e" "-"*<sub>opt</sub>* digits)*<sub>opt</sub>*

Everything there is "optional". That doesn't, however, mean that nothingness should be taken as a number. Nor does it mean that (for example) `.e` is a valid floating point number. It does mean that almost any individual piece can be omitted if some of the others are present. You don't need digits both before *and* after the decimal point, so each is optional in itself--but one or the other has to be present, so `1.` and `.1` are both valid, but just `.` isn't. Likewise, the `.` is optional as well--something like `1e50` is a perfectly valid floating point literal, even though it doesn't contain a `.` anywhere.

Those limitations are expressed in the text associated with the syntactic notation itself. What's allowed (or not) has to based on everything taken together, not just on one piece in isolation.